# PHP unable to load Memcached extension due to json?

Tags: php, json, memcached

It says "undefined symbol: php_json_encode" but json is installed already? also, when i add json.so to the php.ini, it say that module is already loaded?

Comment: What PHP version?  Did you compile Memcached yourself, or did you get it from somewhere (`pecl` for instance)?  What Operating System?

Comment: undefined symbol? I'm guessing PHP 5.1, or *worse*.

Comment: PHP 5.3.4, Redhat Enterprise 5, I compiled memcached myself. whenever i try to use pecl, it says it can't find autoconf even though i've tried to install it and the system said it was already installed and the latest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Because you add json.so into php.ini and do not remove the php.d/json.ini**

**Error shows the reason: json.so should be loaded before memcached.so**

Please use `php -m | grep memcached` to check whether memcached.so is loaded successfully.

- If it shows `memcached`, this means it has succeeded.
- If its show like `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0`

Here is the solution:
e.g. your php.ini is /etc/php.ini, your php.d is /etc/php.d/

**Solution 1**

1. comment 'memcached.so' in php.ini
2. `vim /etc/php.d/memcached.ini`
3. add `extension=memcached.so` in /memcached.ini
4. `php -m | grep memcached` to check whether memcached is successfully loaded

**Solution 2**

1. `rm /etc/php.d/json.ini`
2. add `extension=json.so` in php.ini before `extension=memcached.so`
3. `php -m | grep memcached` to check whether memcached is successfully loaded

Comment: Don't remember remember what fixed it in my case, but this is most likely the answer.

Comment: Hello; I encounter the same problem, I don't have /etc/php.d directory. I use php5.6-fpm, how can I fix this problem please?

Comment: If the `/etc/php.d ` does not exist, you can make one, then create a file called `memcached.ini`